# What additional precautions can be taken to prevent unwanted channeling into an if statement when calling a function?

Tags: r

In the code below, when function best() is called, the if statement with "wrong condition, try again" gets triggered despite the outcome argument having heart attack as its input. Why is this the case and what can be done to prevent such occurrences?

```
best("CA","heart attack")

best <- function(state, outcome) {
     #read file function


  dataTable  <- read.csv("outcome.csv", header = TRUE)
  choice <- state
  stateOfChoice <- dataTable[which(dataTable$state == choice),]

  if(outcome != "heart failure" || outcome != "heart attack" || outcome != "pneumonia"){
    print("wrong condition, try again")
    main()
  }

  else if (outcome == "heart attack"){
    #subsetting,selecting column of "Lower mortality estimate [xxxSpecified  Outcomexxx ]"  & the Hospital name attach to it
    heart_attack <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack),]
    hospital <- heart_attack$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

  else if (outcome == "heart failure"){
    heart_failure <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure),]
    hospital <- heart_failure$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

  else if (outcome == "pneumonia"){
    pneumonia <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia),]
    hospital <- pneumonia$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

}





main <- function() {
  print("Type Heart Attack, .....")

  outcome <- readline(prompt="Type your selection ")

  print("Select state")

  state <- readline(prompt ="Type in your selection")

  best(state,outcome)
}

main()
```

Comment: A couple comments - `read.csv` can be relatively slow. If you check the `outcome` value for the wrong conditions *before* `read.csv`, your program will only do the slow `read.csv` step for good inputs. If you want to get fancy, rather than having `best` call `main` recursively on bad input, have `best` throw and error with `stop`. In `main()`, call best inside `tryCatch()`, and have `main` check if this is the error and, if so, give a `message()` and call `best` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The If conditions should be like this (if you want to go with your solution):

```
if(outcome != "heart failure" && outcome != "heart attack" && outcome != "pneumonia") {
   #do stuff
}
```

However, a better approach would be:

```
if(! outcome %in% c("heart failure", "heart attack", "pneumonia"))
```

Alternatively - you can structure your if/else statements in this format:

```
if()
else if()
else if()
else if()
else if()
...
else
  print("wrong condition, try again")
  main()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your correction nicely shows why OP's version is wrong. But writing from scratch, a nicer way to implement is `if(! outcome %in% c("heart failure", "heart attack", "pneumonia"))`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Have amended my answer to incorporate this. Also I didn't realise you can do something like that in R, learnt something new today. Cheers.